# ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE on PC (tablet and phone work fine)

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser

I am facing ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE error while using my browser (both firefox and google chrome) in personal computer runnning both Windows and Ubuntu operating system. I've tried several suggestions from other posts (clean history, cache, etc) but I still can't open some sites because of error. This happened in some sites, while other sites still worked fine. I wonder why this case only happened in my personal computer, but not in my tablet and phone. I can browse the same sites through my phone and tablet. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Is there a programming question here somewhere that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Why did you tag php? There is not php in this question. Also, this is not a programming question.

Comment: my apologize, i've revised the tag. thank you so much guys.